# UnsatisfiedLinkError Arcgis 10.2.3 Android ArcGISRuntime.setClientId

Tags: android, arcgis, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm having a problem with Arcgis SDK for Android which I've never had before.
It seems an issue with its native interface when I call this method:

```
ArcGISRuntime.setClientId
```

I have this method inside `onCreate()` (Application class), so it crashes at the beginning

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeIsClientIdValid
at com.esri.core.runtime.LicenseImpl.nativeIsClientIdValid(Native Method)
at com.esri.core.runtime.LicenseImpl.b(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.android.runtime.ArcGISRuntime$License.b(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.android.runtime.ArcGISRuntime$License.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.android.runtime.ArcGISRuntime.setClientId(Unknown Source)
at com.pkg.manager.AppManager.onCreate(AppManager.java:262)
```

And this is what I found on Arcgis documentation about this method:

> public static LicenseResult setClientId (String clientId)

License an application for basic functionality. This will remove the watermark present in developer mode and must be called in a deployed application. Whenever standard licensed functionality is accessed, a RuntimeException will be thrown.

This method must be called before setting a license with either `setLicense(LicenseInfo)` or `setLicense(String)`. Note that if any standard licensed functionality is accessed before calling this method, an exception will be thrown when this method is called and the application will remain in developer mode.

Parameters

clientId. client ID to set

Returns

LicenseResult.Invalid or LicenseResult.Valid

(https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/runtime/ArcGISRuntime.html)

Any ideas, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` normally means the application can't load a native library it needs, even though the Java wrapper for that library is present. If the Java wrapper were also missing, your code wouldn't compile.

Did you switch from an earlier version of ArcGIS to ArcGIS 10.2.3 in this project? If so, it is possible that the project still has the native libraries from the old version of ArcGIS, which didn't have a `setClientId` method, even though the project has the Java libraries from the new version of ArcGIS, which do have `setClientId`.

Assuming you're in Eclipse, right-click the project and choose **ArcGIS Tools > Fix Project Properties**. That should replace the old native libraries with the 10.2.3 native libraries.

Answer (score -1):

http://maroofi.github.io/ceal/ for removing watermark from screen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.