# com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.6-2 with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, arcgis

How to use com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.6-2 with proguard enabled?
I am trying

> -keep class com.esri.** { *; }
>    -keep interface com.esri.** { *; }

but it is not helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34335933/1276636) for it, and included this to my proguard rule file.

> ```
> -keep class com.esri.** { *; }
> -keep interface com.esri.** { *; }
> -keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
> -dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.**
> -dontwarn jcifs.http.**
> ```
>
> worked for me.