# Didn't find class "com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment"

Tags: android, proguard, esri-maps

I am using ESRI maps in my android app. I want to Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize my app for that I enabled R8 in my application in `gradle.properties` file by adding this line:

```
android.enableR8 = true
```

along with this, I enabled these by adding the following lines in app-level build.gradle

```
debug {
   minifyEnabled true
   shrinkResources true
   zipAlignEnabled true
}

release {
   minifyEnabled true
   shrinkResources true
   zipAlignEnabled true
}
```

I have tried to add the following things in progaurd-rules.pro file to keep these at run time.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34807601/2462531

```
-keep class com.esri.** { *; }
-keep interface com.esri.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.**
-dontwarn jcifs.http.**
```

But still am facing the same issue when I run the app getting crashed with the following error message:

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment" on path: DexPathList

Need any link or suggestion to ESRI progaurd rules would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got resolved by

> Uninstall and reinstall

;)